# How to set the RAW_CONTACT_ID when create new Contact

Tags: android

when i wanna create a new contact, i think i must set a RAW_CONTACT_ID. if not how do these code perform well. am i right? IF NOT, how did it know these data belong to the same contact. IF YES, how to set the RAW_CONTACT_ID? maybe the question can be say like this: how can i get the new RAW_CONTACT_ID which is not exist? then post my code(i set 0 to the RAW_CONTACT_ID):

```
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
            .newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
            .build());

    // ------------------------------------------------------ Names
    if (displayName != null) {
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(
                        ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                .withValue(
                        ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME,
                        displayName).build());
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------ Mobile Number
    if (mobileNumber != null) {
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(
                        ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                .withValue(
                        ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                        mobileNumber)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
                .build());
    }
    context.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use int rawContactInsertIndex = ops.size() as below.

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
        int rawContactInsertIndex = ops.size();

        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI).withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null).withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null).build());

        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI).withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex).withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, personalVcard.getFirstName()).build());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have spotted some weird issue on JB with the same code which worked fine on previous versions of android. When you ask to create contacts sharing the same base name then the creation is not going the way it should and the raw contact ID returned by withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0) seems to be the same.

For example, try creating Contact1, Contact2 and Contact3: the weird stuff begins. You most likely get no contact visible but an attempt to delete the contact using the API will result in telling you that the contact actually exists.

I'm not sure if that's a consequence of wrecking my Jelly Bean platform or if it's a common issue on android builds. Note that I'm refeering to a platform under development.

Has anyone seen this, on 4.1.2 for example?

Answer (score 0):

This block of code will save contact name with mobile no.

```
private void saveContact() { 
  this.sessionpref.setPreference("Saved", "Done");
  ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList();
  ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
      .withValue("account_type", null).withValue("account_name", null).build()); 

  if (this.DisplayName != null) {
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
        .withValueBackReference("raw_contact_id", 0)
        .withValue("mimetype", "vnd.android.cursor.item/name")
        .withValue("data1", this.DisplayName)
        .build());
  } else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Contact Exist", 3000).show(); 
  } 

  if (this.MobileNumber != null) {
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
        .withValueBackReference("raw_contact_id", 0)
        .withValue("mimetype", "vnd.android.cursor.item/phone_v2")
        .withValue("data1", this.MobileNumber).withValue("data2", Integer.valueOf(2))
        .build()); 
  } else { 
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Contact Exist", 3000).show(); 
  } 
  try { 
    getContentResolver().applyBatch("com.android.contacts", ops); 
  } catch (Exception e) { 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
  }
}
```